# Multiple condition in match use $or or $and

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I know this has been asked before but I can't seem to find the answer, i wannt to filter show with flag 1, flag 2, in $or for seacrhing.

how to if flag 2 condition, flag : 1 and flag : 2, in my code just one flag: 1

```js
information = await information.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "info_text": "$info_text",
            "flag": "$flag",
            "published_at": { $dateToString: { format: "%d/%m/%Y", date: "$published_at" } },
            "approved": "$approved"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            flag: 1,
            $or: [
                { "info_text": { "$regex": req.query.query.generalSearch, "$options": "i" } },
                { "flag": { "$regex": req.query.query.generalSearch, "$options": "i" } },
                { "published_at": { "$regex": req.query.query.generalSearch, "$options": "i" } }
            ]
        }
    },
])
```

Comment: Unclear what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match if it is flag 1 or flag 2 just do the following:

```
$match: {
            $or: [
                {flag : 1},
                {flag : 2}
            ]
        }
```